When I am presenting from macOS, can I temporarily freeze content on the external display while I set up the next scene?
Is it possible, natively or with a software, to allow a mac that is mirroring onto an external display to freeze that display so that the macbook may change scenes and then unfreeze the frame.
For context: I have a mac that is connected to a TV for external use. From where the macbook user is positioned they cannot see the TV so it is easier to mirror the macbook rather than setting it as an external/additional display. However, there are some instances where the person running the macbook will need to change applications or do things behind the scenes and therefore temporarily freeze the TV on whatever the current screen is and then unfreeze it when they are done. I am looking to be able to freeze the screen rather than simply unplugging it and having the screen turn black. Also, I am pretty confident that this would be able to be done with OBS but OBS is pretty taxing on a computer and I was hoping that there would be an easier way to do it.
I have an option of using different macbooks. All of them are currently on the most recent version of sonoma, and ones that have the M1 chip, M2 chip, and the old i9 chip.

OBS is the only way I can think to broadcast a still image and then have the OS move along and then re-broadcast. My answer will be a kludge since it’s doubtful the person making the changes will be able to see what they are doing under the “freeze”

Would you accept a solution to make the external screen go black while you prepare the next scene?

Let’s say you could take a screen shot of the display and then insert that into a program called Desktop Curtain which specializes in automating a setup to present an uncluttered screen.
Would that work?
I suggest third party tools I know work well since I think Apple only has a Screen Curtain function to blank a screen and not freeze the contents.
Also, how would the person preparing know what was going to be on the screen?
